# Can't log into my account-16.04

Tags: 16.04, login

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop for about 4 months now, and everything was fine until about a week ago. Now I can't log in my anymore.

Every time I type my password and click enter, the screen turns black for about 2 to 3 seconds, and then goes back to the login screen again.

There's no password error message just back to the login prompt.

I'm also 100% sure I'm entering the correct password.

this problem started just after I installed an update, could this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

- replace your_username, shown below, with your username

  1. boot the computer and observe the GRUB menu
  2. choose `advanced options`
  3. choose `root access`
  4. type `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`
  5. type `cd /home/your_username`
  6. type `sudo chown your_username:your_username .ICEauthority`
  7. type `sudo chown your_username:your_username .Xauthority`
  8. type `reboot`
  9. login like normal